Load user settings from Sharepoint in Powerapps
New to Powerapps, I am trying to load user settings from a Sharepoint list on app load.  If there is no record, then it should create the row in the list.
Sharepoint list (fields are single line unless sated):
Title, Email, DarkMode (Y/N), Theme

I have tried the following in OnStart on the App, but it is telling me there's an error with the Collect.
Set('UserSettings', {});
Collect(UserSettings, 
    If(
        IsBlankOrError(LookUp('SharepointListName', Email=User().Email)), 
        LookUp('IntegrationReporting-UserSettings', Email=User().Email),
        {Title:"", Email:User().Email, DarkMode: false, Theme: "Green"}
    )
)


Use this formula
With({existingVal:LookUp(SharepointListName,Title=User().Email)},
Patch(SharepointListName,If(IsBlank(existingVal),Defaults(SharepointListName),existingVal),{Title:User().Email})
);

It doesn't call SP twice and is efficient
